# How to fetch the values from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap
`HashMap<String, String> cntrlInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();`
in this map some values are there I need to read the value one by one i want store the values in string.
for example `{GBP,001,101,CHDP}`
now I would like to store 
`String ccy=GBP;` how i can assign the values in string

Comment: It's not at all clear what's in the map. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: private HashMap<String, String> getCntrlInfo(String reqstXml) {
 HashMap<String, String> cntrlInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();     now i am using Iterator <String> It =cntrlInfo.keySet().iterator();and I would like to store each values in a separate string and want to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        HashMap<String, String> cntrlInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        cntrlInfo.put("A", "GBP");
        cntrlInfo.put("B", "001");
        cntrlInfo.put("C", "101");
        cntrlInfo.put("D", "CHDP");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String val : cntrlInfo.values()) {
            sb.append(val);
        }

        System.out.println("sb = " + sb);
        String ccy = sb.substring(sb.indexOf("GBP"), sb.indexOf("GBP") + 3);
        String foo = sb.substring(sb.indexOf("001"), sb.indexOf("001") + 3);
        String bar = sb.substring(sb.indexOf("101"), sb.indexOf("101") + 3);
        String f = sb.substring(sb.indexOf("CHDP"), sb.indexOf("CHDP") + 4);

        System.out.println("ccy = " + ccy);
        System.out.println("foo = " + foo);
        System.out.println("bar = " + bar);
        System.out.println("f = " + f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I would like to store each values in a separate variable

Comment: Thanks a lot sol4me... as we can see this is the static value which we have used here but suppose i got  xml where we don't know what we are going to get then how can we achieve the same. I mean in the HashMap I have xml